# Best way to have a placeholder for individual images from a list of images in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Normally, to have a placeholder for an image in React you can use onLoad in the image tag and update state to set loading to true and then re-render - something like this:

```
class ImageRoll extends React.Component {
  state = {loaded: false};
  
  showImage = () => {
    this.setState({loaded: true});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <img src="/path-to-initial" style={ this.state.loaded ? {display: "none"} :             
    {}} />
        <img src="/path-to-seocndary" onLoad={this.showImage} style={ 
     this.state.loaded ? {} : {display: "none"}} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

However, if you have a list of images that you are mapping over that are in state and you want a placeholder for each individual image, using onLoad becomes cumbersome because you would have to keep track of the images by index and have an additional property for the image in state as an object with something like "isLoaded". But then you are constantly updating the state and re-rendering every time the image is loaded. Is this the best/only was to do this?

Comment: Create an image component with its own internal state that does the logic of tracking the loaded state and displaying the placeholder. Then you can just render as many of those as you want and pass the URL as a prop

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by pass the URL as a prop? Where would I pass it?  Wouldn't the image component already have the URL if it's keeping track of it's loaded or not?

Comment: No this `ImageRoll` component would have a list of images and it maps over them, rendering an image component for each and passing in the URL as a prop, e.g. if the list of images was just an array of URLs for example you'd render `urls.map(url => <Image url={url} key={url} />)`